# Read Mails from Outlook Web App using .net

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook, outlook-web-app

I have code that works for office 365 Exchange web service https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx. However I am now trying to read mail from outlook web app say https://mail.company.com/owa

```
ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
exchangeService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(i_EmailID, i_Password);
exchangeService.Url = new Uri(exchangeURL);
exchangeService.KeepAlive = true;
Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox(email);
FolderId folder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mailbox);
ItemView view = new ItemView(1);
FindItemsResults<Item> items = exchangeService.FindItems(folder, view);
```

If this code works only for Exchange Web Service then what method should I be using to access Outlook Web Access?

Please share me any article or code sample that can help me understand in getting this implemented.

**UPDATE: Exchange Online deprecating Basic Authentication (Basic Auth)**

Basic Authentication is no longer supported by Exchange Online. Use the
OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

```
var confidentialClientApplicationBuilder =  ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                                                                                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                                                                                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                                                                                .Build();

string[] ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };
var authResult = await confidentialClientApplicationBuilder.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
                                                           .ExecuteAsync();

return authResult.AccessToken;
```

and then use the `token` to pass to `OAuthCredentials`

```
exchangeService.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(accessToken);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the version of Exchange running OWA is the same as you are using for Office 365? Also, do you have the correct service URLs for the on-premises version, and are they accessible?

Comment: Thanks for the info. This was so basic. The service URL was wrong in my case.